The purpose of a semicolon in a dictionary definition
Does the semicolon in a definition connecting the independent clauses indicate that there are two separate definitions or simply two parts of a singular definition?

Which dictionary are you using and what does it say about the usage of punctuation in its definitions?

@KillingTime It’s Oxford, and I can’t find where it would explain how it specifically uses semicolons in definitions. However, my immediate understanding is that semicolons are used to conjoin similar or relevant concepts or words to the main definition to build the fullest explanation. But that’s just my gist of it.

This question is similar to: What does the semicolon in the dictionary definition of a word mean?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Note - that earlier question is currently closed (supposedly, "opinion-based"), but I at least have voted to reopen. It doesn't make much sense to say there is no "true" meaning to such use of semicolons.

... But the semicolon usage in such instances is arbitrary (a stipulative usage, perhaps different from how a rival uses a semicolon in its definitions), rather than standard practice, which equally makes such questions unsuitable for ELU which avoids treatments of subjective / in-house practices (song lyrics etc).

@EdwinAshworth: Even if the specific ways semicolons are used in dictionary definitions are arbitrary / inconsistent, I don't think it's defensible to vtc such questions as "matter of opinion". People who use ELU/ELL could still use the information given in the earlier question, and I certainly wouldn't rule out the possibility of a better answer being provided, if it weren't for that (imho misguided) closure. Just because across (and within, I believe) dictionaries there are inconsistencies doesn't mean the semicolons are always entirely arbitrary / meaningless.

...the "subjective" argument might apply to, for example, Why does this lyric fragment use unusual syntax? AND Why does this OED definition include a semicolon, but that definition doesn't? But What do semicolons usually mean in OED definitions? is a significantly different (and imho usefully answerable) question.

@FF I seem to remember that styleguide-specific usage questions were considered too arbitrary for a site aimed at standard usages. And when it comes to how punctuation is used in-house in various publications ....
